# Jquery scrollable autocomplete - detect bottom

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i have the following jquery :

```
$( "#input-name" ).autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            if (!names.length){
                                names = [NoResultsLabel];
                            }
                            response(names);
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                            for(var i=0;i<data.schools.length;i++){
                                if(ui.item.label == names[i]){
                                    document.getElementById('filter[id]').value = ids[i];
                                    i = data.schools.length;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

i added this css to make it scrollable :

```
 <style>
    .ui-autocomplete {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .ui-state-focus {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
</style>
```

and i want to detect when the user scrolled to the bottom and launch an ajax request, because there are too many rows matching the same name (im searching schools by their name and the on select im returning the coressponding id

i tried this

```
 jQuery(function($) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').on('scroll', function() {
                if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                    requests++;
                    getSchools();
                }
            })
        });
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

i found out what was wrong, it was the selector, i found this workaraound

```
$("selector").autocomplete( "widget" ).scroll(function(){
                    ...
                });
```

but call this function only after the autocomplete has been initialized